# Python for loop sort files and get the recent added

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting the right text file but it prints in vertical like one by one letter per row.

Like this outhput

I want to print SAMPLE.txt in 1 row or 1 line.

This is my code

```
for file3 in sorted(files, key=lambda file3:      
    os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(a2, file3)),reverse=True)[0]:

  print(file3)
```

Comment: Please correct the syntax errors.

Comment: Why i cant use print(file[0])?